# Python: How to convert below for loop output into a list?

Tags: python

I am new to python, sorry for the entry level question
I want to save below result into a list.

```
for i in range(true_k):
    print("Cluster %d:" % i),
    for ind in centroid[i, :5]:
        print(' %s' % terms[ind])
```

Comment: You aren't creating a list anywhere? You'll want to look up how to create a list and then append to the list. in terms of "save below result into a list" what are you trying to save exactly?

Comment: Please be more specific about what the issue is.

Comment: I tried to create a list in the beginning, but not sure how to append the result back to the new list.

Answer (score 1):

1) Create the empty list
2) Use the append method of lists 
Something like:

```
mylist = []
for i in range(true_k):
    print("Cluster %d:" % i),
    for ind in centroid[i, :5]:
        print(' %s' % terms[ind])
        mylist.append(terms[ind])
```

Comment: Thanks Sam,besides terms[ind], I also would like to append Cluster name in the list

Comment: Same thing. If you want a new entry, then just append(i).